# Infinispan spike on response time

Tags: infinispan

We have an infinispan cluster of two. Some days ago one of the hosts crashed, taking down one of the host-controllers.

Somehow as a result of this, we say an unacceptable increase in infinispan response time. It went from a couple of miliseconds to 15-20 seconds.

I am trying to investigate this, and cannot find anything. There are timeouts and exception in the log files, but nothing that is specific to this period.

My client timeouts are 10 second, but the spike is almost double that time.

Comment: Failure detection and excluding the crashed node from the cluster view takes a while, and Infinispan will not confirm writes until all key owners either respond or are excluded from the view. If the spike subsided after the new cluster view was installed, then it's expected behaviour.